How to Load Templates in Django for specific application?
So I am learning Django at in advanced level. I already know how to include templates from BASE_DIR where manage.py is located. However I wanted to know how to locate templates in the specific app in Django.
For example, I have a project named mysite and an app called polls.
I then specify the templates directory in settings.py:
DIRS=[os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")]

However, I do not know how to set a templates directory specific to the polls app. This is the project structure:
.
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
├── mysite
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── polls
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── static
│   │   ├── images
│   │   ├── scripts.js
│   │   └── style.css
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
└── templates
    ├── polls
    │   └── index.html
    └── static
        ├── images
        ├── scripts.js
        └── style.css

I wanted it to look like this.
.
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
├── mysite
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── polls
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── static
│   │   ├── images
│   │   ├── scripts.js
│   │   └── style.css
│   ├── templates            <- New
│   │   ├── polls
│   |   │   ├── index.html
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
└── templates
    ├── polls
    │   └── index.html
    └── static
        ├── images
        ├── scripts.js
        └── style.css


If you have the app specific templates located at polls/templates/polls/, then you need to add that path to TEMPLATES in settings.py as shown below:
TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'polls/templates')], # here the app template path is set 
            'APP_DIRS': True, 
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                    'django.template.context_processors.request',
                    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                ],
            },
        },
    ]

And while rendering template the path should have a folder prefix like
render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)

UPDATE: as in above settings APP_DIRS is set to True, django will automatically look into <yourapp>/<templates> directory for the templates even if the app template paths are not explicitly specified.

To ensure Django uses your app-specific templates located at "polls/templates/polls/", update settings.py:
'DIRS': ['polls/templates'], Add app template path here
When rendering, include the folder prefix in the path:
render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)

'polls/templates' is a relative path, it's best if you make that an absolute path instead of relying on people running the code from the same working directory. Also since  APP_DIRS is set to True adding polls/templates to the template directories isn't really needed.

Django search for templates in all DIRS mentioned in TEMPLATES in settings.py file.
For DIRS=[os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")], django will search on "templates" directory.
Accessing template for specific app let say "polls"
For that, wherever you are referring template, you need to mention directory from root excluding template folder.
E.g.
for referring template index.html
you should mention it like
template_name="polls/index.html"

